# Heroku PostgreSQL problem finding the item with the highest rating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

On my local pc I get 4 konkurrancer that have the highest rating (mysql). But on heroku I get four konkurrancer wish have no rating (PostgreSQL).

My controller:

```
@konkurrancergode = Konkurrancer.find(:all, :order => "rating DESC", :limit => 4)
```

My view:

```
<% @konkurrancergode.each do |vind| %>

<%= render :partial => 'konkurrenceras', :locals => { :vind => vind } %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: @konkurrancergode = Konkurrancer.find(:all, :order => "rating DESC nulls last", :limit => 4)

Comment: Dup of your other question, right?

Comment: Yes you could call it a dup, because it is the same problem PostgreSQL

Comment: This is a good example of why it is a bad idea to develop an app using a different database than you're going to deploy on. ActiveRecord is able to smooth over many database differences, but there are plenty of differences that can still bite you.

Comment: can you verify that the rating is actually getting saved?

Comment: I've had a similar problem, you probably need to look at a couple of things:
1. the type of your column you're sorting on. (MYSQL and Postgres may treat them differently)
2. how mysql and postgres treat that type.
3. how you've populated the column....are there any unexpected or blank values. For example if your sorting on an integer, then it's probably well defined and it might just be a case of how each database treats a "blank". I think you may want to provide a bit more information to get a better answer. But hopefully that's something to go on. Regards
Stew